# ¿Como llenar una tableView con una HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Quiero que mi tableView muestre en sus respectivas columnas la Key que corresponde a un numero de cuenta de un banco y el Value a el saldo en ella tal como la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si quizas estare realizando algun mal uso del tableView al ser observable List ya que lo intente pero al momento de crear la cuenta solo me muestra el valor en la 2 columna y no el Key que corresponde la  # De cuenta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de mi clase controladora con el cual refresco la tabla en cada creado de cuenta es:

```
private void refrescarCuentas() {

    ListaCuentas.getItems().clear();

    Iterator lisCuent = modelFactoryController.getBanco().getListaCuentasBanco().entrySet().iterator();
    for (String key : modelFactoryController.getBanco().getListaCuentasBanco().keySet()) {
        for (Double value : modelFactoryController.getBanco().getListaCuentasBanco().values()) {
            listaCuentas.add(new Cuenta(key, value));
            ListaCuentas.setItems(listaCuentas);
        }
    }

}
```

Ya he depurado el metodo y deberia funcionar ya que en el mensaje que me muestra el JOptionPane me indica de que si capturo la "Key"...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
agradezco la ayuda.

Etiquetas e inicializable por si se encuentra alli el error:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Cuenta> ListaCuentas;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Cuenta, String> nunCuenta;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Cuenta, Double> saldo;
@FXML
private ObservableList<Cuenta> listaCuentas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@FXML
private void initialize() {

    /*
     * @Author Santiago Poveda Garcia Luis Felipe Toro
     *
     * @Date: 19/03/2021
     */

    nunCuenta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("#Cuenta"));
    saldo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Saldo"));
    ListaCuentas.setItems(listaCuentas);
    refrescarCuentas();
}



public void crearCuenta() {
    listaCuentas.clear();
    String clienteSelecCuen = cbClienteCuenta.getValue();
    Double saldoInicial = Double.parseDouble(tfSaldoInicial.getText());
    int tipoCuenta = 5;
    int bTipo = cbTipoCuenta.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    String numeroCuenta = "";
    if (bTipo == 0) {
        tipoCuenta = 1;
        numeroCuenta += "A_H";
    }
    if (bTipo == 1) {
        tipoCuenta = 2;
        numeroCuenta += "C_O";
    }

    Iterator listaClient = modelFactoryController.getBanco().getListaClientes().iterator();

    while (listaClient.hasNext()) {
        Cliente client = (Cliente) listaClient.next();
        if (client.toString().equals(clienteSelecCuen)) {
            numeroCuenta += client.getCedula();
            client.crearCuenta(numeroCuenta, saldoInicial, tipoCuenta);
            modelFactoryController.getBanco().crearCuenta(numeroCuenta, saldoInicial, tipoCuenta);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Cuenta de cliente creada y agregada al banco, numero cuenta:" + numeroCuenta);
            refrescarCuentas();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `String` que se pasa como parámetro al contructor de la clase `PropertyValueFactory` es el nombre de la propiedad dentro de la clase de los elementos que agregas a la tabla (en tu caso `Cuenta`).

Esto quiere decir que JavaFX buscará el *getter* correspondiente a la propiedad especificada en el `PropertyValueFactory`: para una propiedad `cuenta` se buscará por el método `getCuenta()`.

Sin ver el código de la clase `Cuenta` debes hacer algo como esto:

```
nunCuenta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cuenta"));
saldo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("saldo"));
```